# how to install library for Mcrypt in centos

Tags: php, linux, algorithm

I install Mcrypt on centos .but I can not use mcrypt algorithms and mcrypt modes .default directory for mcrypt algorithms and  mcrypt modes is /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt but /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt directory is empty.how i can enable mcrypt algorithms and mcrypt modes ?
php version is 5.6
and centos version is 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the mcrypt php module like this:

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

And restart your apache or nginx server.